# Software to help people analyze source code: class has what features, work flows

Tags: open-source

Is there a company or software for helping people analyze source code?

As in GitHub, there is a repo. In general is hard to read the source code, so is there any recommended software for analyzing source code?

I want these features:

1. display a class has what features.
2. display the software work flows and one flow use what instances.